# Creating a vertical list of text that changes order on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, css

I am trying to modify the example found here:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 30px;
}

h2 {
  font: 400 40px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  font: 200 20px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

li:last-child {
  border: none;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;

  -webkit-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}

li a:hover {
  font-size: 30px;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Zurich</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Geneva</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Winterthur</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lausanne</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lucerne</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So that:

- The middle item in the list is already expanded at start
- OnClick of any other elements the list shifts and the clicked item will move to the middle and be expanded
- The opacity of the first and last elements of the list are decreased

Is this accomplishable in javascript or CSS? I have been reading about nth-child but I am trying to understand how to actually implement it. I understand nth-child can help me with the opacity case but is the only way to reorder the list (and animate the reordering eventually) possible with javascript? Or is CSS animations the way to go?

Comment: You will need Javascript. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: I did research which is why I talked about CSS nth-child but how that could only help me solve the opacity task but not with the re ordering of list components with animation